# how to log failures in php unit?

Tags: php, phpunit

How to log only failures in an external file, from php unit?  I want the complete information, including actual value, expected value, line number etc.  Right now I am using fwrite and logging all pass and fail tests into a file, is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 5):

See the [Chapter on Logging in the PHPUnit Manual](http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/logging.html).

The "correct" way to do that would be to write a custom Logger and hook that into PHPUnit's Logging API. Or [extend PHPUnit's standard Listener](http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/extending-phpunit.html#extending-phpunit.PHPUnit_Framework_TestListener) to write any errors to file.

You can setup any custom Loggers and Listeners in your phpunit.xml file. See the Appendix in the PHPUnit Manual for the appropriate markup:

- http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html

An alternative to writing your own logger, would be to just transform the regular HTML output with an XSLT to only provide the errors:

- http://edorian.github.io/2011-01-19-creating-your-custom-phpunit-output.formats